Multi-Column Drag and Drop Cards with Variable Heights Using Angular Material CDK Drag and Drop
I am working on a project where I need to display a list of draggable cards. I'm using material CDK Drag and Drop for this functionality. Each card represents a person and includes a variable number of hobbies, resulting in cards of different heights.
Current Issue
The drag and drop functionality works perfectly when the cards are displayed in a single column. However, when I arrange the cards in a multi-column layout, the drag and drop experience becomes very buggy. Issues include:

Jittering when dragging cards
Unpredictable drop placement

Here's a GIF demonstrating the problem:
Drag and Drop Jittering
What I've Tried
I have attempted several CSS layouts to resolve this, including:

display: inline-block;
display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;
Setting a fixed column-count based on display size

However, all these approaches lead to similar issues with the drag and drop functionality.
Requirements

The cards should be arranged in a full-width, multi-column layout.
The row height should not be dictated by the tallest card in the row like a flex-grid would do. In fact, there should be no rows at all.

Any advice or solutions to achieve smooth drag and drop in a multi-column layout with variable card heights would be greatly appreciated.
Here is a minimal example on stackblitz

This question is similar to: Angular CDK drag and drop issue inside CSS flexbox. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

From this thread, I found this working stackblitz

@Andrej Great find! Also from your thread, following the GITHUB link comes up with this stackblitz, which might be slightly better because it has variable width items.

NOTE: With the new version of cdk-drag you can choose cdkDropListOrientation="mixed" see docs
In older versions, I made this stackblitz that "interchange" -not reorder-
My idea is to have severals cdk-list with an unique cdk-drag inside
To maintain the "grid", at fisrt calculate the with and the height and fixed as [ngStyle] of the cdk-list.
This makes that the "cards" are "interchange" NOT reorder
The code becomes like
<div cdkDropListGroup>
  <div class="containerList" id="cont">
    <div
      *ngFor="let person of persons; let i = index"
      cdkDropList
      cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
      cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"
      id="top"
      class="wrapper"
      [style.width.px]="elements[i]?.width"
      [style.height.px]="elements[i]?.height"
      [cdkDropListData]="{ item: person, index: i }"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="dropPerson($event)"
    >
      <mat-card #drag cdkDrag class="person-box">
        <mat-card-header>
          {{ person.name }}, {{ person.profession }}
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>Hobbies:</p>
          <div *ngFor="let hobby of person.hobbies">
            <mat-card class="hobby-box">
              {{ hobby }}
            </mat-card>
          </div>
        </mat-card-content>
        <div *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

And
  @ViewChildren('drag',{read:ElementRef}) drags:QueryList<ElementRef>
  elements:any[]=[]

  persons: Person[] = [...]

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.calculeDimensions()
    })
  }

  dropPerson(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
    const currentIndex=event.container.data.index
    const previousIndex=event.previousContainer.data.index
    const tmpPerson={...this.persons[currentIndex]}
    const tmpElement={...this.elements[currentIndex]}

    this.persons[currentIndex]=this.persons[previousIndex]
    this.persons[previousIndex]=tmpPerson

    this.elements[currentIndex]=this.elements[previousIndex]
    this.elements[previousIndex]=tmpElement
  }

  calculeDimensions()
  {
    this.elements=this.drags.toArray().map(x=>{
      const rect=x.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect() 
      return {width:rect.width,height:rect.height}
    })
  
  }
}

